# FormData to send file+data

Tags: jquery, ajax, multipartform-data, form-data, asyncfileupload

I am trying to upload some form data and a file to REST endpoint. I have written the following code -

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

   var data = new FormData();

  //upload file append to formdata
  $("#catItemData #uploadC").on('change', function(){
          $this = $(this);
          var file = $this[0].files[0];   
          data.append("xlsx",file);               

 //input fields append to formdata
  $("#catItemData #catSubmit").click(function(){
      var formD = {
              name: $("#name").val(),
              type: $("#type").val()
      };
      for (var key in formD) {
          data.append(key, formD[key]);
      }       
        $.ajax({            
               type: "POST",
               url: "http://localhost:8086/service/create",        
               data: data,
               contentType: false,
               cache: false,
               processData: false,
               success: function(response, status, xhr) { 
                       //response
                    }
              });   
      });
  });
```

This however does not upload any file content and gives me a 415 unsupported media type error. This is how the payload looks like -

------WebKitFormBoundaryANhANgazbC1YNo1u
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="xlsx"; filename="testfile.xlsx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

------WebKitFormBoundaryANhANgazbC1YNo1u
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

hello

------WebKitFormBoundaryANhANgazbC1YNo1u
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="type"

PLATFORM

What am I possibly missing out here ? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The REST endpoint doesn't recognize that file format.

Comment: Why not using [Jquery form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) ?

Comment: I tested the backend using the command prompt and it promptly uploaded an excel file without any hassle. Do I need to modify content type here for the file so it can go through ? The backend is equipped to handle multipart/form-data and application/octet-stream type of content.

Comment: I will give this a try now @Ali Sheikhpour .

Comment: I am getting the same 415 error even after using Jquery form. I'm clueless right now.

Comment: Check the Network tab of developer tools, and compare what gets sent when you do a normal upload of the file and when you use the AJAX code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare `data` variable under method, No need of `change` event on file input if no any validation on change of that file. No need of var `formD`  under click function. Simply your code should be like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 



  $("#catItemData #catSubmit").click(function(){
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append('name', $("#name").val());
      data.append('type', $("#type").val());
      data.append("xlsx",$('#uploadC')[0].files[0]); 
        $.ajax({            
               type: "POST",
               url: "http://localhost:8086/service/create",        
               data: data,
               contentType: false,
               cache: false,
               processData: false,
               success: function(response, status, xhr) { 
                       //response
                    }
              });   
      });
  });
```

Comment: That worked thank you. Also I had to add class="input-file" in my file input for the data of the file to be processed.